# Loading ViewBinder after an event

Tags: java, android

I am trying to update my listview (list of contacts) using the information I got by reading data from Firebase (where the contacts are synced). Basically I am trying to change the colors of the contacts that are backed up in Firebase.

```
final SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder binder = new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

            // IF USERID MATCHES
            // DO STUFF, EG. tv.setBackgroundColor(......);

            return false;
        }
    };
    mAdapter.setViewBinder(binder);

    final Cursor c = mAdapter.getCursor();
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        final String userID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Phone._ID));
        userRoot.child(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            /* CALLS THE BINDER ON THIS USERID */
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
```

I am having trouble understanding what to pass and how to update the ViewBinder when I enter onDataChange function.

Comment: `ViewBinder binder` is supposed to be called by `mAdapter`, not by you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `CursorAdapter` backwards.  You don't get the cursor and read the data from it; the `ListView` does that.  Your job is to *provide* a cursor.  When you have the cursor, you call `CursorAdapter.changeCursor()` and the `ListView` will see that you changed the cursor and do its update.

So if I understand correctly what you are doing, you have a `Cursor` with contacts from your device, coming from the Contacts `ContentProvider`, I assume.  Now, you are going to merge that data with the Firebase data, which is basically JSON.

So here is the recipe:

First create some classes to provide a data model for the Firebase data, and have some methods that will load their data from JSON.

Next, create a subclass of `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder` that you will set in adapter method `setViewBinder()`.  Your subclass will need some kind of method to accept the JSON data from Firebase.  Let's say you have a method like `setFirebaseData()` for example.

Somewhere along the way you get a cursor of Contact data from the system, and call `changeCursor()` on the adapter to hook those up.

Now, when the `onDataChange` is triggered, you would read the JSON data from the `DataSnapshot` into your model, and call that `setFirebaseData()` method with your model.

After you load the Firebase data, you have to tell the adapter that its data has changed.  I've never done this with a `CursorAdapter`, saying it's changed when it really hasn't. You would either call `notifyDataSetChanged()` or just call `changeCursor()` and give it the same cursor it already has.  But somehow you have to convince the adapter that it's time to update.

Once the `ListView` sees the adapter has changed and starts its update, your
`ViewBinder.setViewValue()` will get called.  The cursor is already positioned for you, so you just call `getString()`, `getInt()`, etc. for the columns in your cursor.  Between the contact data in the cursor or the cursor position, there is something that will correlate to the Firebase data that has been set up.  So if you need to change a color based on the Firebase data, you look up the contact there.  You are essentially joining the cursor data with the Firebase data.

If it's still confusing, do some study on the Model/View/Controller design pattern and learn how `ListView` and `ListAdapter` work in regards to MVC.